# Updating a model using a dynamic serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I set up a serializer that is able to dynamically serialize the desired fields as specified in the Django Rest Framework docs.

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

```
>>> class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
>>>     class Meta:
>>>         model = User
>>>         fields = ['id', 'username', 'email']
>>>
>>> print(UserSerializer(user))
{'id': 2, 'username': 'jonwatts', 'email': 'jon@example.com'}
>>>
>>> print(UserSerializer(user, fields=('id', 'email')))
{'id': 2, 'email': 'jon@example.com'}
```

How would I set up the view to allow editing by post method?
I tried something like this.

```
views.py

class UserDetails(self, pk):
    def post(self, request, pk, format=None):
            fields = form_fields_map[request.data['form_info']['index']]['main_info']
            user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
            user_serializer = UserSerializer(user, request.data['main_info'], partial=True, fields=fields)
            if user_serializer.is_valid():
                user_serializer.save()
                return Response(user_serializer.data)
            else:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
```

but I get this error.

```
`update()` did not return an object instance.
```

Comment: U used badly named variables `user_serializer` and `customer_serializer`, its copy-paste literal error ?

Comment: Yeah, I must have missed that.  I didn't copy my exact code but mixed it with the code from the docs.  I'll fix that.

Comment: Same question still though.

Comment: For sure: your `UserSerializer` does not override `update` method ?

Comment: It looks like it does.  I added an update method on the serializer and it works.  Is there a way to dynamically determine which fields will be updated though?  Right now I can only get it to work by hardcoding each possible field.

Comment: Did you even test it ? - maybe it work right now. Im not sure that serializer `fields` attribute will exclude update fields but logically it should.

Comment: It works now.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you answer by serializer `update` method ?

Comment: `def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)`

I just added this to the serializer since it looks like the update method needed to be added again.